# How Can I Make the Condition For IsNullOrEmpty for Empty cell in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I have A table grades

```
    id          |   Marks
----------------+----------
    1           |    
    2           |    33

for record in (select Marks from grades)
loop
 marks=rec.Marks;
 if(marks is null) then
   marks=0; 
 end if;
end loop;
```

> My Problem is in if condition how to write the condition for marks is
>   null, marks is a integer type

Comment: Do you want to _change_ the data i.e. run an `update` statement, or do you just want to display a zero instead of a `null`

Comment: I just want to make 0 instead of null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change this on retrieval you can also use CASE or COALESCE

```
SELECT col1, COALESCE(marks, 0) as MARKS from grades
```

or

```
SELECT col1, CASE WHEN marks IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE marks END AS marks
  FROM grades
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the values, use an [update](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) statement:

```
update grades
  set marks = 0
where marks is null;
```

To insert the data use an `insert` statement with a coalesce:

```
insert into temp_table (col1, marks)
select col1, coalesce(marks, 0)
from grades;
```

Comment: @Shafi74: there is no `if`in SQL

Comment: It is working but I want to  change it with the help of if condition.                        you are using where marks is null,similarly in if condition what can i put,      if(marks is null) it is not working

Comment: i am using postgresql

Comment: @Shafi74: as I said: there is no `if` in the SQL query language. Also doing updates in a loop is a really bad idea.

Comment: i am not updating my original table.i am inserting into temporary table .loop is one part of my function not only for updating

Comment: @Shafi74: well you said you wanted to change the data, not insert it. See my edit. You might want to consider telling us what the **real** problem is you are trying to solve. Doing stuff like that in a loop is almost always a really bad idea.